# Count amount of directives is created

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got two directives, one directive is a sub-directive to the other one.
In the sub-directive there will be a `ng-repeat`. So there will be `x` amount of sub-directives depending on the list it will repeat. My question is: Is it possible for the base directive to know how many amount of sub-directives there will be? The base directive will then know when to concat all the values from the sub-directive and pass it on.

In this example the `$scope.length` of the list is know. But because of the `ng-if` 3 sub-directives is created and not the length of `$scope.length` which is 5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<test-directive>
    <test-sub-directive ng-repeat="l in list" ng-if="l > 2" variable="{{l}}">{{l}}</test-sub-directive>
</test-directive>

<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

  app.directive('testDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controllerAs: 'testCtrl',
      controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function testCtrl($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        $scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5];

        this.testFunc = function () {

            //When everything is fetched from the sub-directive send it to another function
        }
      }]
    };
  })
  app.directive('testSubDirective', function () {
    return {
      require: '^test-directive',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, testCtrl) {


        testCtrl.testFunc();
      },
    };
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIUXSWL47ZC9

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute `ng-if` with a filter. Now you can use the result to determine `length` on your parent directive. [This is a working edit of your sample](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIUY7IVG7XB6)

Comment: Thanks it works, but I've some restrictions, I can't call a function from the scope to modify my list of data. I've to keep it like this: `ng-repeat="l in list"`

Comment: Then apply the filter function on the `list`. Something like `ng-repeat="l in list | filter:<filter function>"`

Comment: A function on `ng-repeat` will work if its output is consistent with a given input; or else u'll hit an infinite loop and angular will 'throw up'

Comment: Sorry, for not explaning my question better. But I don't really want to add anything to my HTML-markup. I solved it using this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIV1ZCNJ8H17

Comment: @PresidentCamacho, you forgot to decrease counter on scope $destroy